# home-brew on macOS big sur

Tags: path, homebrew, export

I installed home-brew via

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

and whenever I type in `brew` I get:

```
Warning: /opt/homebrew/bin is not in your PATH.
```

I have tried several solutions online, none of them worked!

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to install Homebrew on a new M1 Mac? According to [Homebrew's FAQ](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-should-i-install-homebrew-in-the-default-location) for Apple ARM Macs, the executable is located on a different path `/opt/homebrew/bin`.

So you need to add the path to your shell profile or rc file (Bash, ZSH...)

```
echo "export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Restart your shell, and enjoy.